# can any one help me to both enable checkbox and list of textview in android

Tags: android, eclipse

Sir i am having checkbox and list in that i can click checkbox its get checked but my list as became disable so plzz any one help me to enable both list view and checkbox in andriod

Comment: You will need to rephrase your question , right now its pretty confusing :-)

Comment: Dint get even a word :-(

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, want to comment but don't have the reputation yet. Are you saying you want to be able to view the list only when the checkbox is ticked? If this is the case, you can set the lists visibility attribute like so:

```
android:visibility="invisible"
```

and then make it visible on the onClick method like so:

```
if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
  list.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 }
```